# Updating record in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update my table in database using codeigniter but my data is not updated.

here is my view code:

```
<div class="review_all">
  <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
  <div class='fb_review_panel'>
    <div class='review_date'>
    <form action='<?php echo base_url('testimonials/update'); ?>' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <span class='month_t'>
      <select class='select_update' name='month_update'>
        <option value='<?php echo $row->month?>'> <?php echo $row->month?> </option>
        <option value='January'> January </option>
        <option value='February'> February </option>
        <option value='March'> March </option>
        <option value='April'> April </option>
        <option value='May'> May </option>
        <option value='June'> June </option>
        <option value='July'> July </option>
        <option value='August'> August </option>
        <option value='September'> September </option>
        <option value='October'> October </option>
        <option value='November'> November </option>
        <option value='December'> December </option>
      </select>
      </span> <span>
      <?php
                    echo "<select name=day>";
                    ?>
      <option value='<?php echo $row->day?>'> <?php echo $row->day ?> </option>
      <?php
                    for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){
                    echo "<option value=$i>$i</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
      </span> <span class='index_t'>
      <select class='select_update' name='power_update'>
        <option value='<?php echo $row->power_t ?>'> <?php echo $row->power_t ?> </option>
        <option value='st'> st </option>
        <option value='nd'> nd </option>
        <option value='rd'> rd </option>
        <option value='th'> th </option>
      </select>
      </span> <span class='year_t'>
      <select class='select_update' name='year_update'>
        <option value='<?php echo $row->year ?>'> <?php echo $row->year ?> </option>
        <option value='2013'> 2013 </option>
        <option value='2014'> 2014 </option>
        <option value='2015'> 2015 </option>
        <option value='2016'> 2016 </option>
      </select>
      </span>
      </div>
      <div style='display:none<?php echo $row->trash_default ?>; font-family:lato;font-size: 14px;background:#1abc9c;color: white;border-radius: 12px;letter-spacing: 1px; '> Visible </div>
      <div style='display:<?php echo $row->trash_default ?>; font-family:lato;font-size: 14px;background:#e74c3c;color: white;border-radius: 12px;letter-spacing: 1px; '> Hidden </div>
      <div class='review_line'> <span> <i>
        <textarea name='review_update' class='ta'>
            <?php echo $row->review ?>
            </textarea>
        </i> </span> </div>
      <div class='user_details'> <span> <b> -
        <input class='input_update' name='source_update' type='text' value='<?php echo $row->source ?>' />
        </b> </span> <span>
        <input style='display:none;' name='key_update' type='text' value='<?php $row->r_id ?>' />
        </span> <span>
        <select class='select_update' name='trash_reupdate'>
          <option value='none' selected='selected'> Hide / Unhide </option>
          <option value=''> Discard </option>
          <option value='none'> Restore </option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='save' />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Here is my model code:

```
public function edit_testimonial($data){
        extract($data);
        $this->db->where('r_id', $key_update);
        $this->db->update($testimonial, array('month' => $month_update,'day' => $day_update,'power_t' => $pow_update,
            'year' => $year_update,'review' => $review_update,'source' => $source_update,'trash_default' => $tr_update));
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my controller code:

```
public function update(){
        $data=array(
            'testimonial'=>'testimonial',
            'month_update'  => $this->input->post('month_update'),
            'day_update'    => $this->input->post('day_update'),
            'pow_update'    => $this->input->post('power_update'),
            'year_update'   => $this->input->post('year_update'),
            'review_update' => $this->input->post('review_update'), 
            'source_update' => $this->input->post('source_update'),
            'tr_update'     => $this->input->post('trash_reupdate'),
            'key_update'    => $this->input->post('key_update'),
        );

        if($this->testimonial_model->edit_testimonial($data)) // call the method from the model
            {
                echo "update successful";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "update not successful";
            }
    }
```

After editing when i click on submit button then it show message updated successfully but when i checked data base table then there is no update done.

Comment: 'testimonial'=>'testimonial' is a string, should that not be an ID?

Comment: Your function always `return true;` instead of code output. Return `true` or `false` depending upon conditions.

Comment: I didn't  understand marc what r you saying

Comment: so what i do pupil .please suggest

Comment: Please help me to find out the solution

Comment: First your `edit_testimonial()` returns always `true`. Second why you are sending the table name you have multiple tables for testimonials? And Third the table structure will help us to help you.

Comment: if($this->db->affected_rows()){
    return true;
}
 return false;

Comment: If possible show your table structure. create table i mean..

Comment: r_id,month,day,power_t,year,review,source,trash_default

Comment: there is my table column

Comment: in your update function you create a $data array, after that make a print_r($data); and print us your output pls

Comment: after using print_r function it display....   Array ( [month_update] => May [day_update] => 1 [pow_update] => st [year_update] => 2016 [review_update] => asfadas dasdasd [source_update] => dsasdas [tr_update] => none [key_update] => )......why key_update is blank

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what this comments are all about but try the following

instead of

```
<input style='display:none;' name='key_update' type='text' value='<?php $row->r_id ?>' />
```

try this

```
<input name='key_update' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $row->r_id ?>' />
```

your echo was missing

Comment: style does not matter unless you have disabled it.

Comment: yeah AJ you are right - the missing echo is the answer ;)

Comment: Its not working and print_r function display this.... Array ( [month_update] => May [day_update] => 1 [pow_update] => st [year_update] => 2016 [review_update] => asfadas fdsfsd [source_update] => dsasdas [tr_update] => none [key_update] => )

Comment: show me your model where you read out all your data in order to create your forms

Comment: @sintakonte yes you are right, I missed this. By the way, she also has to modify model code according to my answer to make code work perfectly.

Comment: I used both of your code but showing this result..  Array ( [month_update] => May [day_update] => 1 [pow_update] => st [year_update] => 2016 [review_update] => asfadas sdasdasda [source_update] => dsasdas [tr_update] => none [key_update] => ).....here is key_update value is missing

Comment: sintakonte ...please call me in chat..then we can communicate properly

Comment: i can do that, but i've no idea how to do that ;)
i think you've to open a room isn't it ?

Comment: please help me to the solution ..why key_update value is not taken..please help

Comment: yeah open a chat i'm available

Comment: but i dont know how to create chat

Comment: plese click this link sintakonte.....    https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112501/updating-record-in-database-using-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

change your

```
<input style='display:none;' name='key_update' type='text' value='<?php $row->r_id ?>' />
```

to this

```
<input style='display:none;' name='key_update' type='text' value='<?php echo $row->r_id ?>' />
```

and in your controller paste this code:

```
public function update(){
        $data=array(

            'month_update'  => $this->input->post('month_update'),
            'day_update'    => $this->input->post('day_update'),
            'pow_update'    => $this->input->post('power_update'),
            'year_update'   => $this->input->post('year_update'),
            'review_update' => $this->input->post('review_update'), 
            'source_update' => $this->input->post('source_update'),
            'tr_update'     => $this->input->post('trash_reupdate'),
            'key_update'    => $this->input->post('key_update')
        );


        if($this->testimonial_model->edit_testimonial($data)) // call the method from the model
            {

             echo "update successful";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "update not successful";
            }
    }
```

and in your model this code:

```
public function edit_testimonial($data){
        extract($data);
        $this->db->where('r_id', $key_update);
        $this->db->update('testimonial', array('month' => $month_update,'day' => $day_update,'power_t' => $pow_update,
            'year' => $year_update,'review' => $review_update,'source' => $source_update,'trash_default' => $tr_update));
        if($this->db->affected_rows())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@nushrat
1- First of all you are having form in loop, so there will be multiple forms, but you will be having only the last form information or may be random.
2- In your update function of controller validates that are you receiving the data correctly or not by writing `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';` before assembling the $data array and after assembling the data array write this code to check if $data variable is populated properly or not. `echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';` and die(); or exit after it to stop going any further.
3- If in the second step you found your data is set properly than jump over to your modal edit_testimonial function and right before the extract($data); write `echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';` to verify if you have received the data properly there too or not.
4- Indent your code properly always for the readability.

Let me know your response at that.